# Quickest Way to Revert Spaces to TABs in VIM

Tags: vim, vi

I have always been one to replace TABs in VIM with x amount of spaces (usually 4).
Four lines I almost always use in my .vimrc config file are:

```
set tabstop=4 

set shiftwidth=4

set expandtab

syntax on
```

Basically, there are moments when I NEED to use a single TAB (such as Makefiles), and I don't know how else to work around that other than leaving the file, editing my .vimrc, and then reloading the file of interest.

That said, what is the quickest way (from within VIM) to revert it back to using TABS, and then reverting back to my original settings? I'm looking for the least-hassle, least-keystrokes solution.

Comment: Vim knows about Makefiles and will insert the correct sign when you edit them. Is this another kind of file that you are editing? (yes know that you have found the answer just want to check this) :)

Comment: @Sedrik Yes, Makefiles were actually what spurred the question. My VIM didn't seem to do any of the behavior you described though. Any insight on that?

Comment: Are you sure? I have never had any troubles editing Makefiles. If i recall correctly it might be the case that vim still shows you the file according to your settings but when writing to disk it should write the correct result. Dont have a Makefile available to verify this but during my years of development I have never had an issue concerning tabs in Makefiles.

Comment: @Sedrik So I just realized..I am accustomed to naming my makefiles "Makefile." Apparently that capitol 'M' is voiding the behavior you mentioned. However, "makefile" automatically had vi set up the tabbing behavior! So, either I can start naming them accordingly, or I can just use the filetype binding `autocmd FileType make setlocal noexpandtab.` But..hmm...I think the lowercase letter is, in this case, the solution.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

VIM will automatically enable the TAB for a makefile, assuming you name it "makefile," as opposed to "Makefile." Not sure why VIM still doesn't detect the type with a lower-uppercase difference, but such is life. (@Sedrik)

That aside, other alternative solutions are:

**Filetype Binding (@ThorstenS @tungd):**

`autocmd FileType make setlocal noexpandtab`

**RealTime Switch (@ThorstenS):**

Assuming the .vimrc configuration mentioned in the question, do:

`:set noet` (to switch from spaces to TAB)

and `:set et` (to switch back)

Comment: You mean `:set noet` and `:set et`, I guess (this is about the position of the colon).

Comment: Good catch @Jan-PhilipGehrcke. Fixed.

Comment: Hmm. The behavior is the same for me for both `makefile` and `Makefile` (Vim 7.4.1689 on Ubuntu 16.04). Anyhow, the `autocmd` line in the `.vimrc` works perfect.

Answer (score 24):

Just use the magical escape key available in insert mode.

On the *NIX's it is ^V by default when you are in insert mode. On Windows, you need to find out what the magical escape character is - ^V is taken for something else; I think it may be ^Q or ^S?

So! In your makefile:

```
this: this.c
<C-V><Tab>cc this.c
```

where the usual meanings apply:

means hit ctrl-V (you should see a ^ hiding away under the cursor)
 - hit the tab key. Bingo.

Works for me.

Note: if you use vim settings or startup code which smashes tabs as you read a file, this obviously is a short-term fix. I prefer to learn how to use the retab command to ensure a file is tab-clean, because I don't like a file to be touched unless I consciously choose to do so.

Answer (score 11):

Just type `set noexpandtab` . Perhaps you bind this to a function key.

Comment: Or better, bind this to a filetype: `autocmd FileType make setlocal noexpantab`

Comment: I'd bind it to the file type, so I get that automatically for Makefiles.

Comment: @tungd Nice. I'm using that filetype binding now, since I'll be messing with Makefiles quite frequently. Thanks!

Comment: @tungd typo in `noexpantab` should be `noexpandtab`

Answer (score 3):

Only this configuration helped me solve this problem.

```
filetype plugin indent on
filetype detect
autocmd FileType make set noexpandtab
```

Answer (score 0):

Vim defaults to `tabstop=8` and `noexpandtab`, so the defaults are well suited to working with Makefiles. If your .vimrc uses custom options for `tabstop`, `expandtab`, etc., one simple solution is to bypass your .vimrc while working with Makefiles.

From the manpage (emphasis mine):

> -u {vimrc} Use the commands in the file {vimrc} for initializations. All the other initializations are skipped. Use this to edit a special kind of files. ***It can also be used to skip all initializations by giving the name "NONE"***. See ":help initialization" within vim for more details.

Since I can never remember the necessary flag/value/formatting, I've created a Bash alias which remembers for me: `alias vimnone='vim -u NONE'`

Answer (score -1):

You can create a custom configuration per file type.

```sh
mkdir -p ~/.vim/after/indent
echo 'set noexpandtab' >> ~/.vim/after/indent/make.vim
```

Basically, here we created a new indent configuration for makefiles that will be loaded after other scripts.

---

[source](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Indent-with-spaces-not-TABs.html)